# Back up SSIS Catalog Database on Azure

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-sql-database

I am looking for a way to back up SSIS Catalog Database that was deployed on Azure.  I looked through the documentation here:

- [SSIS Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/catalog/ssis-catalog?view=sql-server-ver15)

It seems like the first step of doing that would be backing up a master key, which is not supported on Azure, so I tried to look for a more general way of backing up SQL Server on Azure like this method of using Azure Portal GUI:

- [Azure Backup: SQL Databases and How To Back Them Up](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/hosted-database-backup-azure)

Or using SSMS export wizard:

- [Export a Data-tier Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/export-a-data-tier-application?view=sql-server-ver15)

However, it seems like they all fail to back up SSIS Catalog DB, giving this Error SQL71564:

One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package.

> Error SQL71564: Error validating element Signature for '[internal].[get_database_principals]': The element Signature for '[internal].[get_database_principals]' cannot be deployed. This element contains state that cannot be recreated in the target database.

> Error SQL71564: Error validating element Signature for '[internal].[get_principal_id_by_sid]': The element Signature for '[internal].[get_principal_id_by_sid]' can...

I am investigating the details of these error messages, and they seem to mean that I should change the metadata or structure of the SSISDB, which I can't really do at the moment.  Is there any way to backup SSIS DB on Azure without really changing SSIS DB?

Answer (score 0):

Please try generating a DACPAC from the command line.

You can follow these articles:

1. [Using SQLPackage to import or export SQL Server and Azure SQL DB](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/using-sqlpackage-to-import-or-export-sql-server-and-azure-sql-db/ba-p/368861)
2. [Generating an SSISDB DACPAC](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/09/generating-ssisdb-dacpac.html)